# Transport-type duality for preduals of $C^{k,1}$-functions

Tags: pr.probability, sobolev-spaces, duality, optimal-transportation, preduals

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty, simply connected, and open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some positive integer $d$.  Let $k$ be a non-negative integer.  Consider the Banach space $C^{k,1}_0(\Omega)$ equipped with its normed by
$$
\|f\|_{C^{k,1}} := \max_{|\beta|\leq k} \max_{x_1,x_2\in \Omega}\, \|D^{\beta}f(x_1)-D^{\beta}f(x_2)\| + \max_{|\beta|=k} \sup_{x_1,x_2;\,x_1\neq x_2}\, \frac{\|D^{\beta}f(x_1) - D^{\beta}f(x_2)\|}{\|x_1-x_2\|}.
$$
Now, consider the closure of the set of point-evaluation maps $\delta_x:f\mapsto f(x)$ in the dual space of $C_0^{k,1}$ with respect to the dual norm
$$
D(F,G) := \sup_{f\in C_0^{k,1}(\Omega),\,\|f\|_{C^{k,1}}\leq 1}\, (F-G)(f);
$$
we denote this closure by $\mathcal{P}^{k,1}_0(\Omega)$.

---

If $k=0$, $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d$, then $\mathcal{P}_0^{k,1}(\Omega)$ is the 1-Wasserstein space and there is a nice transport-type duality describing $D|_{\mathcal{P}^{k,1}_0(\Omega)}$ in terms of optimal couplings.

However, what about the general case; especially for $k>0$.  Is there an optimal transport type description of $D|_{\mathcal{P}^{k,1}_0(\Omega)}$?  That is, I am looking for a Kantorovich-esque duality for $D|_{\mathcal{P}^{k,1}_0(\Omega)}$ on $\mathcal{P}^{k,1}_0(\Omega)$

---

**Relevant Literature**

- [On properties of geometric preduals of Ck,ω{\mathbf C^{k,\omega}}Ck,ω spaces - A. Brundyi](https://ems.press/journals/rmi/articles/16387)